# Three.js lighting changes based on bundler?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Today, I transferred the portfolio project I'm working on from standard html over to the vite bundler to handle dependencies easier. I copy and pasted the exact code over and changed the imports (as I was using relative imports before) and everything worked fine, except for how the lighting was appearing.

[image: Seen here.]

The right is the vite bundler, the left is the expected outcome from the relative imports. Would anyone know what I did wrong?

Vite code: https://hastebin.com/sivarerako.js
Previous Code: https://hastebin.com/dafupizoru.js

Answer (score 1):

Your Vite code has two extra lights

```
const aLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.8)
const pLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 2.0, 200, 2 )
scene.add(aLight, pLight);
```

Of course it's going to look brighter than your previous code.

Comment: My bad. Those were added during debugging. Still, without any of those lights, it's still 110% bright.

Comment: Are you sure you're targeting the same version of Three.js? The engine releases a new version once a month, and they've changed their color management recently. My guess is that your Vite build has a newer version installed.

Comment: My vite version is on 0.145.0 while my previous project was on 0.140.2. Is the color updates within this version gap? Also, what might a solution be?